# Resharper: Code snippets with tab+tab

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-snippets

In VS, to use snippets (for example auto-implented property) I typed "prop", then hit TAB twice.
However R# (I'm using R#6) inserts the snippet after ONE tab, causing me to always mistype something.
Is there an option somewhere, where I can set it to use **two tabs**?

Comment: i have this exact issue, the double-tab is so much in muscle memory, and i dont want to "unlearn" it since at home i dont have resharper, so i use double-tab there.. this majorly f***s me over on a daily basis :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way that I'm aware of that would let you reassign deployment of ReSharper live templates to two tab hits instead of a single hit.

However, until you've got used to the single-tab deployment, you can Shift+Tab to go back to the previous template hotspot, which prevents messing things up.

Another option would be to selectively turn off ReSharper live templates that conflict with Visual Studio snippets that you're used to deploy on a regular basis.
To do that, go to ReSharper > Live Templates, and in the Templates Explorer, under Live Templates, either deselect "Predefined templates" altogether or expand this category and turn off selected templates - in your example with "prop", you should turn off ReSharper's "prop" and propg (the latter is under "Imported Visual C# snippets")